# When choose .NET 6 Web API in VS 2022, Program.cs is not creaing

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to start creating a WEB API in .NET 6, in Visual Studio 2022 17.1.6, with following info:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.1.6
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.1.6+32421.90
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03761

Installed Version: Professional

.NET Core Debugging with WSL   1.0
.NET Core Debugging with WSL

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   17.1.363.30963
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012   17.1.363.30963
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   17.1.363.30963
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.1.363.30963
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.1.363.30963
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.1.0-5.22165.10+e555772db77ca828b02b4bd547c318387f11d01f
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0
Fabric Diagnostic Events

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   17.0
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   2.1.161+abc97ecc7d.RR
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.2
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

NuGet Package Manager   6.1.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.0.0.2206201+62a2c1d6162f828801565a7ca26d9d48b810a05b
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.0.62203.25080
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Syntax Visualizer   1.0
An extension for visualizing Roslyn SyntaxTrees.

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.1229.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.1.0-5.22165.10+e555772db77ca828b02b4bd547c318387f11d01f
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.1.0-beta.21610.4+07b5673e4f2fa7630e78abe37f16b372353a7242
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions   1.0
View, manage, and diagnose containers within Visual Studio.

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers
```

I chose from template the ASP.NET Core Web API, then provide name of project

[image]

[image]

After `Create`, I got only:

[image]

Without Program.cs

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve issue.

Seems that local path (after clone repository which has space or special character in its name) is saved like `C:\test\My%20Api`

If change location to a name that does not contain special character (you can specify different location when clone repo) with valid one like `C:\test\MyApi` then the creation will work.

Comment: Hi Snake Eyes, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)